# Text size and high contrast accessibility jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile

I am new to jQuery mobile and I am trying to achieve jQuery mobile accessibility. Text size and high contrast. But in this I want text size and high contrast to be select through select options. Something I find but this is not what I am looking.

"jsfiddle net/DC2Ry/2"

Comment: Please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just include a link to a code hosting site. Your post should stand alone from any other resource; consider what would happen if that site went down in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have altered your fiddle. Did you mean for the top buttons to be dropdowns themselves?

link: http://jsfiddle net/qrf4bcj3/1/

**EDIT**
Check this bad boy out:

```
http://jsfiddle net/qrf4bcj3/2/
```

Comment: Waoo. this is cool omikey. Text size functionality is what i want. Actually i am working on Jquery mobile app and for the setting module i have to add high contrast feature too. any example with such functionality.

Comment: one moment please let me find a pretty picture

Comment: Hey sorry i forgot to mention I dont want image to be affected, I need if the text color is white it should turn black. Mean inverting the original color without affecting picture. Thanks

Comment: That would be inversion, contrast is a little different... here's my last attempt, it is in contrast as well but just for text. sorry I have run out of time. http://jsfiddle.net/qrf4bcj3/4/